# Flatten 3 dimensional array into 2 dimensional array containing a tuple with double strings (immutable)

Tags: arrays, typescript

Given the following (3 dimensional) array:

```js
type ParsedLine = [string, string];
type ParsedLines = [ParsedLine, ParsedLine]

const myArray: (ParsedLine | ParsedLines)[] = [
  ['something', 'somethingElse'],
  [['foo', 'bar'], ['baz','qux']],
  ['another', 'yetAnother']
];
```

What the desired outcome should be (2 dimensional array):

```js
// [['something','something-else'],['foo','bar'],['baz','qux'],['another','yetAnother']]
```

I have looked at the [flatten operator](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten) from Lodash. However, that creates a 1 dimensional array, not a 2 dimensional array.

What I am currently doing is the following:

```js
flattenArray(multidimensionalArray: (ParsedLine | ParsedLines)[]): ParsedLine[] {

  const flatArray: ParsedLine[] = [];

  multidimensionalArray.forEach((item): any => {
    // Why does 'item' need a typecast here?
    const containsSubArray = (item as Array <ParsedLine>).filter((subItem) => Array.isArray(subItem));
    if (containsSubArray.length === 0) {
      flatArray.push(item as ParsedLine);
    } else {
      flatArray.push((item as ParsedLines)[0]);
      flatArray.push((item as ParsedLines)[1]);
    }
  });

  return flatArray;
}

console.log(flattenArray(myArray));
```

While this output is correct, I don't find it very readable. Also, it's not immutable since the push method is used.

And I am not sure why I need to cast 'item'. Does *.filter()* not work on the ParsedLine tuple type?

Comment: What's `(ParsedLine, ParsedLines)[]` supposed to be?  Can you pass this through an IDE and [edit] so it's a [mre]?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAjZPW) meet your needs?  It's kind of hard to know which of those issues to answer, presumably I don't have to worry about "why I need to cast `item`" if I refactor to a readable and immutable version?  Anyway let me know what you want to see here for an answer or if I've missed something.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. This answer is perfect. Instead of trying to destructure the 2 dimensional array, you make the 1 dimensional array also a 2 dimensional array and then flatten it.

Comment: I wrote up an answer and [edit]ed the question to show `(ParsedLine | ParsedLines)[]` instead of `(ParsedLine, ParsedLines)[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each entry in `myArray` you'll need to check if it's a `ParsedLine` or a `ParsedLines`.  If you have a value `x` of type `ParsedLine | ParsedLines`, then checking whether `x[0]` is a `string` should be sufficient to distinguish them.  Unfortunately the compiler's built-in [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) won't automatically narrow `x` for you when you check it, because `ParsedLine | ParsedLines` is not a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  Therefore if you'd like the compiler to follow your logic, you might want to create a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) with a *type predicate* return type:

```
const isParsedLine = (x: ParsedLines | ParsedLine): x is ParsedLine =>
  typeof x[0] === "string";
```

So now when you call `isParsedLine(x)` the compiler will understand that a `true` result implies `x` is a `ParsedLine` and that a `false` result implies `x` is a `ParsedLines`.

---

Okay, right.  For each entry `cur` in `myArray`, we need to check if it's a `ParsedLine` or a `ParsedLines`.  If it's a `ParsedLine` then you want it to appear as an entry in `flattenedArray`; otherwise if it's a `ParsedLines` then you want *its entries* to appear as entries in `flattenedArray`.  There are multiple ways to do that.  Here's one way using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add either `cur` or `...cur` onto the end of the accumulator:

```
const flattenedArray = myArray.reduce<ParsedLine[]>(
  (acc, cur) => isParsedLine(cur) ? [...acc, cur] : [...acc, ...cur],
  []
);
```

which could be refactored so that `[...acc,`  happens unconditionally:

```
const flattenedArray = myArray.reduce<ParsedLine[]>(
  (acc, cur) => [...acc, ...isParsedLine(cur) ? [cur] : cur],
  []
);
```

which could be further refactored to use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) if it exists in your environment:

```
const flattenedArray = myArray.flatMap(
  cur => isParsedLine(cur) ? [cur] : cur
);
```

All of those yield the same result:

```
console.log(flattenedArray);
// [["something", "somethingElse"], ["foo", "bar"], 
//  ["baz", "qux"], ["another", "yetAnother"]]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=4.5.4#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)